# Install Mac OS X El Capitan on used Macbook Pro from USB doesn't see the USB

Tags: macos, usb, install

I have just purchased a used Macbook Pro A1286, "Core 2 Duo" 2.66 15" (SD.) I'm new to Apple products, and I'm trying to install Mac OS X El Capitan from a USB bootable pen drive I just did. The problem is that when I put in the pen driver, turn on the mac, and hold option key, it doesn't see the usb pen drive.. Any help would really be appreciated, I'm trying to get an OS installed on this device..

Comment: What OS is already installed on the Macbook? If none how do yuou know it works as that does not seem what a reasonable seller would do.

Comment: How did you prepare the USB-drive?  Special care is needed.